# How to automatically create the minimal size of the viewbox which fits for the complete content?

Tags: svg

I have a simple or complex SVG graphic. For example a rotated rectangle.
Without calculating you cannot know the minimal size of the viewbox, where the graphic fits into completely.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
<rect x="20" y="0" width="100" height="20" transform="rotate(45)" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

The result is, that the graphic does not fit into the viewbox.

Is there any method, how to get an the minimal size of the viewbox, where the graphic is shown completely?

Ideally I do not want to declare a size/ratio of a viewbox. I just want that the minimal size is a result of the content of the SVG graphics.

Is there any disadvantage, when I do not declare the viewBox attribute at all?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is wrapping the transformed rectangle in a `<g>` element and then get the value of the bounding box for `theG`. Next you use the values of the bounding box (`BB`) to reset the `viewBox` of `theSVG`. I hope it helps.

```js
// the bounding box for the wrapping g
let BB = theG.getBBox();


theSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `${BB.x} ${BB.y} ${BB.width} ${BB.height}`)
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="theSVG" viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="300">
  <g id="theG">
<rect x="20" y="0" width="100" height="20" transform="rotate(45)" fill="black" />
  </g>
</svg>
```